# How to configure a conditional nginx proxy pass

Tags: proxy, webserver, nginx

I am trying to create a conditional proxy that will proxy url (from localhost:7012) requests that end with 'DirectToHTTP' to another http server (at localhost:8012).
The rest of the config file works well (the redirection to localhost:877X in https) but the proxy does not work.
What am i getting wrong? (I am new with nginx and web servers)
Thank you very much! :)

Nginx config file main content:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {

        listen       7012 ;
        server_name   someservername;
        set $new_uri  "${request_uri}";

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

            if ($new_uri ~ (.*)DirectToHTTP) {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8012;
                break;
            }

        }

        if ($request_method = GET) {
            return 301 https://localhost:8773$new_uri;
        }
        if ($request_method = POST) {
            return 307 https://localhost:8773$new_uri;
        }  
        if ($request_method = PUSH) {
            return 307 https://localhost:8773$new_uri;
        }       

        return      301 https://localhost:8773$new_uri;
    }
}
```